# Checking Current File System with Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I need my perl script to check the file system type of the computer it's running on.  What is the easiest way to do this? (on Linux)

Comment: _file system type of the computer its running on_ - computers don't have filesystems, storage devices do.

Comment: The answer to this depends greatly on the type of OS - if you know this, it's relatively easy, but if you don't, it's quite hard. Are you running under linux by any chance?

Comment: The computer may have multiple disks and multiple partitions, each one with one different file system. Do you want to know the type of root partition or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a linux command `df -T` to determine filesystem

You can invoke it from your script and parse the output:

```
my $filesystem_info = `df -T`;
```

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to do what you want is (a) decide *which* mount you are talking about and (b) find its entry in `/proc/mounts`.

On Linux, `/proc/mounts` lists all mounted file systems.  The format of each line is "device mount-point fs-type mount-options'.  It is human-readable; `cat /proc/mounts` and you should get the idea.

(Note that `/etc/fstab` only lists the file systems that get auto-mounted at boot time.  That can be different than what is mounted at the time the script runs for all sorts of reasons, most notably automounters.  `/proc/mounts` is what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing the `/etc/fstab` file to find it out.
Beware there might be multiple filesystems in this file, you have to pick the one you want.